# Google Sheets: split cells vertically and copy surrounding row entries

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, spreadsheet

I need to do the following to optimize this sheet:

1. split each multi-line cell in column B so each email address will appear on a new row inserted under the original row.
2. Copy the data from cells in column A on the original row
3. I tried split+transpose formulas and a script I found here, but that is returning an error.

Here is the script:

```
function split_rows2(anArray) {
  var res = anArray.reduce(function(ar, e) {
    var splitted = e.slice(3, 12).map(function(f) {return f.toString().split(",").map(function(g) {return g.trim()})});
    var temp = [];
    for (var j = 0; j < splitted[0].length; j++) {
      temp.push(e.slice(0, 3).concat(splitted.map(function(f) {return f[j] ? (isNaN(f[j]) ? f[j] : Number(f[j])) : ""})).concat(e.slice(12, 20)));
    }   
    Array.prototype.push.apply(ar, temp);
    return ar;
  }, []);
  return res;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
=ArrayFormula(QUERY(SPLIT(FLATTEN({A2:A&"♦"&SPLIT(B2:B,",")}),"♦"),"select * where Col2 is not null",0))
```

---

**Before:**

| Col1 | Col2 |
| --- | --- |
| A | 1,2,3 |
| B | 4,5 |

**After:**

| Col1 | Col2 |
| --- | --- |
| A | 1 |
| A | 2 |
| A | 3 |
| B | 4 |
| B | 5 |

Answer (score 0):

A multiline cell implies that they are delimited by line feeds '\n' not commas

```
function myfunk() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet0');
  let vs = sh.getRange(2, 1, sh.getLastRow() - 1, sh.getLastColumn()).getValues();
  sh.getRange(2, 1, sh.getLastRow() - 1, sh.getLastColumn()).clearContent();
  vs.forEach((r, i) => {
    let t = r[1].toString().split('\n');
    if (t.length > 1) {
      t.forEach((e, j) => {
        if(j == 0) {
          r[1] = e;
        } else {
          let arr = Array.from(r, x => '');
          arr[1] = e;
          vs.splice(i + j, 0 , arr)
        }
      });
    }
  });
  sh.getRange(2, 1, vs.length, vs[0].length).setValues(vs);
}
```

Sheet 0 after:

| COL1 | COL2 | COL3 | COL4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 4 | 19 | 17 |
| 5 | 8 | 10 | 7 |
| 0 | a | 21 | 19 |
|  | b |  |  |
|  | c |  |  |
| 9 | 14 | 17 | 0 |